# Detect changes in table, based on height and weight

Tags: php

I want to detect any changes in a table, based on the height and weight. The table will be long since more data will be added once per day. But for now, it's only 3 rows long.

Here's how it looks like right now (I have only included the change of the weight because I don't know how to include the height):

```
# RESULTS
Loggades            Längd     Vikt     BMI  
2018-07-19, 15:40   1m 86cm   85 kg    25 (normal)  
2018-07-18, 15:40   1m 85cm   84 kg    25 (normal)  down
2018-07-17, 01:26   1m 86cm   86 kg    25 (normal)  down


# TABLE
echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="width-datetime">Loggades</td>';
            echo '<td class="width-height">Längd</td>';
            echo '<td class="width-weight">Vikt</td>';
            echo '<td class="width-bmi">BMI</td>';
            echo '<td class="width-change"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';


    echo '<tbody>';

        # LOOP
        foreach($get_data AS $data) {

            # VARIABLE
            $change_ = $data['data_weight'];


            echo '<tr>';

                # HEIGHT
                echo '<td>';
                    echo datetime($data['datetime_occured'], true);
                echo '</td>';

                # HEIGHT
                echo '<td>';
                    echo substr_replace($data['data_height'], 'm ', 1, 0).'cm';
                echo '</td>';

                # WEIGHT
                echo '<td>';
                    echo $data['data_weight'].' kg';
                echo '</td>';

                # BMI
                echo '<td>';
                    echo calculate_bmi($data['data_height'], $data['data_weight']);
                echo '</td>';

                # BMI
                echo '<td class="width-change">';
                    # echo '<i class="fas fa-chevron-'.$change.'"></i>';
                    echo $change;
                echo '</td>';

            echo '</tr>';


            # VARIABLE
            $change = ($change_ < $data['data_weight'] ? 'up' : 'down');

        }

    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Here's how I want it to looks like:

```
Loggades            Längd     Vikt     BMI  
2018-07-19, 15:40   1m 86cm   85 kg    25 (normal)
2018-07-18, 15:40   1m 85cm   84 kg    25 (normal)  down
2018-07-17, 01:26   1m 86cm   86 kg    25 (normal)  up
```

Comment: You should put `$change = ($change_ < $data['data_weight'] ? 'up' : 'down');` right after `$change_ = $data['data_weight'];`. Also use a counter to skip the output for the first entry in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make any difference. It still shows "down" for the data from 2018-07-17.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should look like this:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($get_data AS $data) {
  if($x != 0) {
    $change = ($change_ < $data['data_weight'] ? 'up' : 'down');
  } else {
    $change = '';
  }

  echo '<tr>';

  # HEIGHT
  echo '<td>';
      echo datetime($data['datetime_occured'], true);
  echo '</td>';

  # HEIGHT
  echo '<td>';
      echo substr_replace($data['data_height'], 'm ', 1, 0).'cm';
  echo '</td>';

  # WEIGHT
  echo '<td>';
      echo $data['data_weight'].' kg';
  echo '</td>';

  # BMI
  echo '<td>';
      echo calculate_bmi($data['data_height'], $data['data_weight']);
  echo '</td>';

  # BMI
  echo '<td class="width-change">';
      # echo '<i class="fas fa-chevron-'.$change.'"></i>';
      echo $change;
  echo '</td>';

  echo '</tr>';

  $x++;

  $change_ = $data['data_weight'];

}
```